# Архитектура веб-приложения

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Написал для курсовой работы сайт на PHP. У меня есть файлы .php, в которых HTML находится вперемешку с PHP. Никакие фреймворки я не использовал, писал на чистом PHP. Файлы .css и .js подключаются через стили и скрипты. В курсовой работе имеется пункт, в котором нужно описать архитектуру веб-приложения. Я в основном знаю MVC. Но так, как я писал сайт - это не MVC, так как вид и контроллер находятся вместе. Даже преподаватель сказал об этом. И у меня вопрос, какая архитектура в таком случае получается? Думаю несколько дней, но никак не могу что-либо сообразить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно написать в данном разделе работы?Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Скажите вашему преподавателю, что вы используете принцип [KISS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF))

Comment: " так как вид и контроллер находятся вместе." - а модель, типа, в каком-то другом? (:

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Спагетти-код вот ваша архитектура.

Comment: @DiD интересный принцип, не слышал о таком. Как думаете, такое и вправду можно сказать или написать в пояснительной записке?)

Comment: @ArchDemon к сожалению, отчасти да. До этого никогда не сталкивался с веб разработкой. Походу изучения сделал работу, работает отлично, но в плане архитектуры не очень хорошо получилось...

Comment: Вы понимаете, что каждой работе свой инструмент. Любая архитектура приложения даёт какие-то плюсы и минусы в решении поставленной задачи. И если первое перевешивает второе, то мы берём данную архитектуру. Так же и у вас, если ваши цели и задачи были выполнены оптимальным образом, то к вам никаких вопросов быть не должно. К примеру, если ваша программа написана в концепции "write once and never run", то вы справились на 146%

Comment: @ArchDemon понимаю. С поставленной задачей я справился. Но вопрос в том, какую архитектуру к такому коду можно приплести. Я понимаю, что здесь никакой архитектуры скорее всего нет. Но от меня требуют её описать... Вот и обратился сюда за советом. Думаю уже, может вообще просто описать архитектуру "Клиент-сервер"...

Comment: Ну если у вас в курсовой есть обязательный раздел с архитектурой, то описание в стиле "клиент-серверная" будет наиболее уместным.

Comment: На самом деле там не один KISS есть, есть еще [Worse is Better](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5), [Don't repeat_yourself](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself) и [You aren't gonna need it](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI). Одного только разбора всех этих принципов хватит на всю теоретическую часть.

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо за совет!